# Override User.Identity.Name in built-in MVC 4 authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a hard time to figure this out and really need this to work. I have to override the value of `User.Identity.Name` in MVC 4 with built-in authentication.

Here's my controller for `Login()`:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    //OLD CODES:
    //if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    //{
    //    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    //}

    // check if correct credentials
    if (ModelState.IsValid && IsValidUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

Note that I modified the `WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password)` into `IsValidUser(model.UserName,model.Password)` to check the user account and it works fine.

What I want is to override the value of `User.Identity.Name` if login is successful.

Here's my `IsValidUser(model.UserName,model.Password)` method:

```
public bool IsValid(string _username, string _pwd)
        {
            _username = _username.Trim();
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            string strCon = string.Format(GlobalDBStrings.CONNSTRING, _username, _pwd);
            conn.ConnectionString = strCon;
            bool isConnected = false;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                if (conn.State.ToString() == "Open")
                {
                    // I WANT TO MODIFY THE VALUE OF User.Identity.Name here
                    // User.Identity.Name = ?
                    isConnected = true;
                }
            }//try
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }//catch
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }//finally
            return isConnected;
        }
```

So far I've tried `User.Identity.Name = _username;` but simply didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using FormsAuthentication you need to set a cookie with the name of the currently authenticated user before redirecting using the [`SetAuthCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx) method:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && IsValidUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("FooBar", false);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Now on the target controller action (`/Home/Index`), `User.Identity.Name` will be `FooBar`.

Usually this happens inside the method you commented and your user is not even authenticated if you do not emit a forms authentication cookie.

As far as the code in your `IsValid` method is concerned, well, all I can say is that IDisposable resources should be wrapped in `using` statements to ensure proper release of resources.

Comment: Does `User.Identity.Name` accessible to all pages? like sessions? Sorry I'm new to MVC 4

Comment: Yes, it's accessible everywhere you have an `HttpContext` which is pretty much in all controller actions and views.

Comment: Yeah. I got it working now. Thanks a lot. But one more question, is it safe? or do you have any suggestions if there's a better way to do this? and by the way, I use Oracle as database.